# hadoop LineReader - Reverse read text files

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, reverse, filereader, reduce

In a scenario we have a bunch of files which we want to read from bottom to top. So to say in reverse order, i.e. last line first, then second last line.

Looking into Hadoop API there are bunch of RecordReader classes such as LineRecordReader which leverages LineReader.
Basically I'd require a ReverseLineRecordReader leveraging a ReverseLineReader. The ReverseLineReader would then read in reverse order lines in from input splits.

This would be very beneficial if you have a large file sorted in some order where you would need to have the first and last entry related to some key. So you would first scan top down and then bottom up.

Since I guess this is not very exotic but couldn't find any implementation I was wondering if someone could help out here.